# Meaning of "Study curriculum with rankings"

Tags: phd, graduate-admissions

I have decided to apply to PhD studies and in one part it says that my CV should contain: *"Study curriculum with rankings"*. 
What does that mean? because they are also asking me to submit my studies transcripts.

Comment: It's ambiguous to me.  I'd contact the department and ask for clarification.

Comment: "See attached transcript."

Answer (score 2):

Study curriculum means the list of titles of courses/subjects and their contents, credits, and so on. In other words, the syllabus.

The term 'Ranking' is generally associated with the institution. Probably they are asking for the ranking of the university/college you attended. 'Ranking' may also imply your position in the class of X number of students. It may also simply mean the semester-wise serial number of courses.

[You can have a look at this link.](http://whitman.syr.edu/recruiters/programs-curriculum-rankings.aspx)

Comment: 'Ranking' may also imply your position in the class of X number of students.

Comment: It may also simply mean the serial number.

Comment: http://whitman.syr.edu/recruiters/programs-curriculum-rankings.aspx

Comment: It would seem strange to put a complete list of courses taken on a CV, especially when the institution is also getting a transcript.  I'm not sure exactly what the application is asking for, but I doubt it's that.  "Syllabus" is itself ambiguous - to me it's a document produced by a course instructor that describes the class policies.  And I don't know what you mean by "*the* ranking" of a university: everybody and their brother seems to publish rankings these days, they're all different, and every school can find some list that ranks them highly.  So that doesn't seem meaningful.

Answer (score 2):

Do these instructions come from an institution in an English-speaking country? If this came from an university in my homeland, I'd interpret it as "list of all courses taken with grades", clumsily translated into English. Besides that, it's not unusual to ask for this kind of information in when applying for a PhD (at least in Italy).